# reading date from a data frame based on conditions in a different data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 data frames.
I need to read in values from one data frame based on values from another

words:

```
words = pd.DataFrame()
words['no'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
words['word'] = ['cat', 'in', 'hat', 'the', 'dog', 'in', 'love', '!', '<3']
words
```

Sentences:

```
sentences =  pd.DataFrame()
sentences['no'] =[1,2,3]
sentences['start'] = [1, 4, 6]
sentences['stop'] = [3, 5, 9]
sentences
```

the desired output is in to a text file:

```
cat in hat
***
the dog
***
in love ! <3
```

however i cant get past this step, i have tried running the following code:

for x in sentances:
    print(words['word'][words['no'].between(sentences['start'], sentences['stop'], inclusive = True)

but am returned with this error

```
 File "<ipython-input-16-ae3f5333be66>", line 3
    print(words['word'][words['no'].between(sentences['start'], sentences['stop'], inclusive = True)
                                                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: Your SyntaxError is because of a needed closing parenthesis to `print()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to solve this,

```
res=pd.DataFrame()
res['s']=sentences.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(words.iloc[(x['start']-1):(x['stop'])]['word']),axis=1)
res.to_csv('a.txt',index=False,header=False,line_terminator='\n***\n')
```

Comment: Quick note: This is exactly what my answer does, but a lot slower because apply sucks in general :(

Answer (score 2):

Set `no` as the index for `words` and then iterate over `sentences` using a list comprehension:

```
v = words.set_index('no')['word']
sentences = [
    ' '.join(v.loc[i:j]) for i, j in zip(sentences['start'], sentences['stop'])
]
```

Or index agnostic:

```
v = words['word'].tolist()
sentences = [
    ' '.join(v[i - 1:j - 1] for i, j in zip(sentences['start'], sentences['stop'])
]
```

```
['cat in hat', 'the dog', 'in love ! <3']
```

Saving to a file should be straightforward from here:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for sent in sentences:
        f.write(sent + '\n')
        f.write('***\n')
```

Comment: Hi @coldspeed. will this work in the case that word no is not the same as the index  number, for example word number could be 10 and index may be 8, as a few word numbers may be missing

Comment: Hi @coldspeed, you are right i tried both examples on a more complex problem and i got a result that was easier to work with. I am new to this site and still trying to understand the site etiquette

Comment: @Pythonuser did you see the first part of my comment? You can still change it assuming that's what you meant to do from the beginning.